# MongoDB: addToSet with dynamical field name

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I need to use a field name by using a variable. How do I do that?

```
let variableName = 'cars';
Collection.update(
    { _id: id },
    {
        $addToSet: {
            variableName: {
                foo: bar
            }
        }
    }
);
```

In this example effectivly should be done like:

```
Collection.update(
    { _id: id },
    {
        $addToSet: {
            cars: {
                foo: bar
            }
        }
    }
);
```

But I need to do this programatically.

Similiar thing with this:

```
var fieldName = 'user';
Collection.find({ _id: id, fieldName + '.language': lang });
```

What is the correct way for doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just update you code to

```
let variableName = 'cars';
Collection.update(
    { _id: id },
    {
        $addToSet: {
            [variableName]: {
                foo: bar
            }
        }
    }
);
```

It'll create dynamic key name.